# Как из командной строки управлять балаболкой?

Tags: cmd, bat

1. Собственно, имеем программу [Балаболка](http://balabolka.site/balabolka.htm)!
2. Она установлена и норм. воспроизводит текст.
3. Голос [RHVoice Mikhail Русский](https://github.com/RHVoice/RHVoice/blob/master/doc/ru/Binaries.md#sapi-5) тоже установлен, разумеется, в качестве синтезатора речи.
4. Как теперь из командной строки передавать файлы 1.txt , 2.txt ... 3.txt;
   чтобы воспроизводить их при запуске из батника?
5. Я пробовал так: качал прогу [balcon.exe](http://balabolka-tts.ru/bconsole.html):
6. Разархивировал в любое место и добавил в папку батник с кодом:

```
pause
balcon.exe -n "RHVoice Mikhail" -f c:\Text\book.txt
pause
```

Задача такая: каким будет батник, чтобы просто воспроизводить текст из 1.txt?
У меня пока что-то воспроизводится, но я не пойму что и откуда, но точно не из `c:\Text\book.txt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас попробовал, завелось. Попробуйте так:

1. запуск cmd в Win10 - обязательно из-под админа.
2. пользуйтесь ключами. Чтобы наверняка, я использовал такой способ запуска:

```
cd C:\Folder
balcon -b 1 -n Irina -f "C:\Folder\File.txt"
```

Описание ключей есть в ридми в архиве с balcon.exe.

> Разархивировал в любое место и добавил в папку батник с кодом

Вы в первой строке пишите pause. Пока не прожмете кнопку, выполнение дальше не пойдет...
Понятно, зачем ставить в конце, но нужно ли оно в начале?)

Что касаемо перебора файлов:

1. в том самом ридми есть ключи, которые позволят получить список файлов сразу, а потом запускать их на "воспроизведение" - либо дожидаясь завершения предыдущего воспроизведения, либо нет.
2. Либо берите все свои `.txt`, которые хотите скормить программе, делаете из них список в другом `.txt`, и вот этот вот **другой** `.txt` передаете в `.bat`.

Вот пример цикла обработки чего угодно из файла (у меня это IP):

```
for /f %%i in (C:\Folder\hosts.txt) do ( //для for так же можно посмотреть справку:
                                         // for /?
    
    ping %%i | find "TTL="
    if errorlevel 1 (@echo %%i >> %folderLocal%\%logFile%) else (@echo It's ok >> %folderLocal%\%logFile%)
)
```

Собственно, тут мы скармливаем нашему `.bat` файл со списком строк, вроде такого:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
…
```

и потом на выполнение в качестве переменной идет каждая строчка из файла. В моем примере - `%%i`.

Comment: Сработало! Cо 2-ого раза, первый раз читал какую-то бурду, как только сменил текст файла File.txt. Содержимое balcon проги скинул в
```C:\Folder```
а дальше как в инструкции Вашей. Только во 2-ой строчке сделал так:  
`balcon -b 1 -n RHVoice Mikhail -f "C:\Folder\File.txt"` Так как у меня другой асистент помошник.

Comment: @ArthurAlunts рад помочь!) Вообще, имена `Folder` и `File` использовал просто для примера, так-то подставляйте туда, что хотите, как оно есть у вас.)
Возможно, файл брали в одной кодировке, а изменили и сохранили уже в другой. Надо ковырять сайт разрабов, может, там чего и написали на эту тему.)
Если не ошибаюсь, `Irina` там предустановлена (или в винде?), поэтому просто выбрал предлагаемое дефолтное значение.)

Comment: Поменял кодировку здесь вот: панель управления/региональные стандарты/вкладка дополительно/ изменить язык системы/поставить галочку/бета версия использовать Юникод UTF-8. И всё заработало!!! ))) Спасибо все минусоидам. (У меня Windows 10)

Comment: @ArthurAlunts сейчас глянул у себя, а оно, оказывается, у меня работало и без этой галочки.) поэтому согласен с модераторами, прям в ответ, наверное, не обязательно это добавлять, а в коммент - самое то. Может, в каком-то из патчей просто пофиксили этот нюанс именно в винде? потому как у меня обновления не отключены, сижу на актуальных версиях.) 
но, если пришлось залезть так глубоко, то замечание полезное, да.))